# How to get member of conference in xmpp?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I have download yaxim source code from github [yaxim link](https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim) Now I want to get the member of 
conference , I tried below code but its not working,

> ```
> String room  = "test@conference.abc";
> Connection xmppConnection;
>         ConnectionThread connectionThread = AccountManager.getInstance()
>                 .getAccount(account).getConnectionThread();
>         if (connectionThread == null) {
>             Application.getInstance().onError(R.string.NOT_CONNECTED);
>             return true;
>         }
>         xmppConnection = connectionThread.getXMPPConnection();
> MultiUserChat userChat = new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection, room);
> Iterator<String> roomUsers  = userChat.getOccupants();
>         System.out.println("roomUsers count === "+userChat.getOccupantsCount());
>         while (roomUsers.hasNext()) {
>             String roomOccupants = (String) roomUsers.next();
>             System.out.println("room users ==== "+roomOccupants);
>         }
> ```

but roomUsers count returns 0.

if any one know other way for getting users list from conference room , then let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to **join** the MUC in order to see its members.

Comment: Hi Flow, I have write above code after joining the conference room